# Where o where has my fav's bar gone?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Just spent 2+ hrs trying to discover where my top horizontal favorites bar went.  I could drag/drop new favs to it and it had >> at the end to that dropped down to a older/larger fav's list

Answer (score 6):

Favorites?  Bookmarks?  Is this for your web browser?  Chrome?  Firefox?  Safari? Internet Explorer?

Well... with Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+B shows/hides the Bookmark Toolbar.

With Firefox, use the View menu at the top, Toolbars, Bookmark Toolbar to bring it back.

With Internet Explorer, use the View menu at the top, Toolbars, Favorites.

Otherwise... we need far more specific information from you.

Comment: I think it's Chrome, based on the question tag. +1 for your shotgun approach, though.

Comment: I assumed it was Chrome first... but "favorites" threw me off.  That's a big IE thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome you can go to Settings (Click on the [image: Spanner icon] in the top-right hand corner of the browser for a dropdown menu). Under the 'Basics' tab in the section titled 'Toolbar' tick the box that says 'Always show the bookmarks bar'.

You can also use Ctrl + Shift + B to toggle the bookmarks bar on and off.